# Class inheritance and parametrized types in Kotlin: Is Subtype Polymorphism possible with generics?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, polymorphism, retrofit

I'm struggling to understand and/or make Kotlin generics & polymorphism work for me. Consider this code:

```
class Item<T: BaseAttributes> {
    var id: Long = -1L
    lateinit var type: String
    lateinit var attributes: T
}

open class BaseAttributes {
    lateinit var createdAt: String
    lateinit var updatedAt: String
}

open class BaseResponseList<T : BaseAttributes> {
    lateinit var items: List<Item<T>> // the collection of items fetched from an API 
}

class FruitAttributes(val id: Long, val color: String /* ... */) : BaseAttributes()

class FruitResponseList: BaseResponseList<FruitAttributes>()

// base service for all types of items
interface ApiService {
    fun getItems(): BaseResponseList<BaseAttributes>
    // fun getItemById(itemId: Long): BaseResponse<BaseAttributes>
    /* other CRUD functions here ... */
}

// service for fruits
interface FruitService: ApiService {
    override fun getItems(): FruitResponseList // get fruit items
}
```

I'm stumped by this compiler error that suggests `FruitResponseList` is not a subtype of the parametrized base class (`BaseResponseList<FruitAttributes>`):

`Return type of 'getItems' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member 'public abstract fun getItems(): BaseResponseList<BaseAttributes> defined in ApiService'`

I try to use declaration-site covariance in BaseAttributes to tell the compiler my intention that a FruitResponseList is a subclass of the base response list like this:

```
open class BaseResponseList<out T : BaseAttributes> {
    lateinit var items: List<Item<T>> // the collection of items fetched from an API 
}
```

leads to this error:

`Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'invariant' position in type List<Item<T>>`

How can I achieve the type-subtype relation between Fruit & Base response lists?

### The Context

I'm implementing the networking code to perform CRUD operations against an API that's based on the [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/examples/) format, thus I created the attributes and data (`Item`) classes to represent the json response objects.

My goal is to reduce the amount of duplicated code so that I only have to write the API service declarations once for every entity in my application (fruits, vendors, buyers, etc). I also want to avoid writing duplicated/boilerplate implementations of the data repository layers for every entity in my app (in the context of clean architecture). I should be able to just specify the business entity-specific types (models/entities) and let the one generic implementation do the work of fetching network data.

I thought it would make sense to use generics and inheritance to achieve this. In this particular example, the idea is that the fruit-specific GET would return a fruit response list, which is a subtype of the base response list. Will greatly appreciate any guidance on this, or alternative approaches to this problem

Comment: Suggested reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm stumped by this compiler error that suggests `FruitResponseList` is not a subtype of the parametrized base class (`BaseResponseList<FruitAttributes>`):

It is a subtype of `BaseResponseList<FruitAttributes>`, which isn't a subtype of `BaseResponseList<BaseAttributes>`.

> I try to use declaration-site covariance in BaseAttributes to tell the compiler my intention that a FruitResponseList is a subclass of the base response list like this:...

This could be a correct approach, but the problem is that `Item` is not covariant (and it can't be because `attributes` is a `var` and its setter takes a `T` parameter). If `Item` can be modified to avoid this, good.

Another approach would be to add a type parameter to `ApiService`:

```
// base service for all types of items
interface ApiService<T: BaseAttributes> {
    fun getItems(): BaseResponseList<T>
    // fun getItemById(itemId: Long): BaseResponse<T>
    /* other CRUD functions here ... */
}

// service for fruits
interface FruitService: ApiService<FruitAttributes> {
    override fun getItems(): FruitResponseList // get fruit items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this :

```
// base service for all types of items
interface ApiService<T> {
    fun getItems(): T
    // fun getItemById(itemId: Long): BaseResponse<BaseAttributes>
    /* other CRUD functions here ... */
}

// service for fruits
interface FruitService: ApiService<FruitResponseList> {

    override fun getItems(): FruitResponseList
}
```

or this :

```
// base service for all types of items
interface ApiService<T : BaseAttributes> {
    fun getItems() : BaseResponseList<T>
    // fun getItemById(itemId: Long): BaseResponse<BaseAttributes>
    /* other CRUD functions here ... */
}

// service for fruits
interface FruitService: ApiService<FruitAttributes> {

    override fun getItems(): FruitResponseList
}
```

You will be bounded to `BaseResponseList<BaseAttributes>` in your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided by Mark and Alexey were very helpful. Particularly, parametrizing the `ApiService` on the `BaseAttributes` was the more flexible option since it allowed functions to take or return both `BaseResponseList` and `BaseResponse` [sub]types.

However, for what it's worth, it turns out that the Retrofit library does not allow its service declarations to extend other interfaces or even to be parametrized, supposedly in favor of composition over inheritance. There's plenty of debate about their decision on this [issue here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/504).
So I ended up creating separate interfaces for every one of my models :/